# Способы получения кода страницы

Tags: vb.net, синтаксический-анализ, веб-программирование

Как получить кода страницы, если содержимое генерируется с помощью javascript.

Мне известны  2 способа:
1)

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.Innertext
```

2) библиотека [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: получение кода и его парсинг — это кардинально разные вещи

Comment: Сейчас уже став немного опытнее я нашел оптимальный способ решения тогда стоявшей передо мной проблемы.Вопрос отредактирован.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант WebClient (не работает)?

```
(New System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("site")
```

Comment: Все работает, просто я искал варианты скачать страницу. Сейчас получив некий опыт, освоил 3 способ.
Выбрал для себя вариант с  httpclient. Скачивать страницы генерируемые на javascript не пробовал, отпала надобность.